# Модуль хранения данных для Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Как реализовать модуль, который будет хранить общие данные, например:

- номер телефона
- email
- адрес
- и т.д.

т.е. данные которые можно было бы использовать в любом месте шаблона, с возможностью изменения в административной части?

Есть идея создать модель, где одно из полей (особый "ключ") по которому можно было бы вызвать определённую запись.

Вот только вопрос, это вообще как нибудь возможно, в шаблоне достучаться до такой записи?

Comment: Добавляете свои templatetags или context_processors и через них стучитесь куда угодно

Answer (score -1):

Сделайте модуль назовите его как-то и импортируйте в другие модули. Там сделайте какой-нить объект, ну, например, такой:

```
class User():
    id_user = 0
    listUser = {}
    
    def __init__(self, name, phone, address, otherthings):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
        self.address = address
        self.otherthings = otherthings
        self.id = User.new_id()
        User.usertolist(self)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f"Name is {self.name}, phone: {self.phone}, adr: {self.address}, other: {self.otherthings}"
    
    @classmethod
    def new_id(cls):
        cls.id_user += 1
        return cls.id_user
    
    @classmethod
    def usertolist(cls, usr):
        cls.listUser[usr.id] = usr
```

где то вызывайте его:

```
first_user = User('Ivan','+7495356882','Moscow','Other things')
second_user = User('Vladimir','+7343257781','Yekaterinburg','Other things')
```

Если проверить что там, то вот:

```
print(first_user)
print(User.listUser.keys())
```

> Name is Ivan, phone: +7495356882, adr: Moscow, other: Other things
> dict_keys([1])

В общем у вас хоть один набор данных для какого то пользователя, хоть много пользователей - у вас все данные будут доступны через вот подобный класс. А уж что делать с данными - ваше дело.

Comment: Странная дичь какая-то, со странной архитектурой, с утечкой памяти и из шаблона обратиться всё равно не получится

Comment: @andreymal  Почему вдруг не получится? И чой то вдруг утечка памяти? Здесь часть класса только для иллюстрации, а не для применения - например вывод строки явно не требовалось, но для иллюстрации - вполне. Любую задачу можно решить разными способами - предложите - свой. А то критиковать каждый может.

Comment: То есть глобальный словарь listUser, в который вы бесконечно складываете данные, вас не смущает? Если получится обратиться из шаблона, то почему вы об этом в ответе не написали? А если это не для применения, то зачем вы вообще написали этот ответ?)

Comment: @andreymal  уважаемый... не так быстро. Вы хотите понять смысл или хотите утвердиться? Вот чего я не могу понять. Если модуль импортировать в модули где нужен этот список пользователей - то он будет там доступен через класс. Наполнение класса - это уже другое, для этого не хватает данных в задаче. Поэтому естественно это лишь пример. Я даже не знаю есть уже готовы ИД этого пользователя или нет. Раз не знаю, значит надо показать что можно и так - я и завожу новый. Если готовый то просто изменить класс. Утечки памяти нет никакой.

Comment: @andreymal Мы с вами не знаем сколько пользователей будет - возможно только два.. то какая к хрену это утечка? Если же 22 миллиона - то лучше хранить в базе... Мы не знаем. Речь вообще выше идет про одного пользователя. Не вижу проблем с данным кодом. Повторюсь - предложите решение лучше. Какие проблемы то? Я только за! Я же не говорю что у меня самое лучшее решение - но моё решение работает, а вашего  - пока не вижу.

Comment: Ну вот вы сами на 22 миллионах пользователей продемонстрировали, что в вашем коде утечка... А вообще вы не ответили на изначальный вопрос. Автор спрашивает про «данные которые можно было бы использовать в любом месте шаблона» — а в вашем ответе ничего про шаблоны вообще нет.

Comment: @andreymal  а если 100 триллионов то и простой базы не хватат.. Давайте о разумных вещах. В модулях можно импортировать другие модули. Слава Богу Python это позволяет делать.  И не надо демагогии - есть что сказать - покажите код.

Comment: Ну так покажите код, как использовать ваше решение в шаблоне? И не надо демагогии: если вы действительно считаете свой ответ решением — ну так покажите пример использования вашего решения в шаблоне.

Comment: Или, возможно, вы даже не знаете что такое шаблон?)

Comment: @andreymal в шаблонах хранится собственно шаблоны документов html. Но ведь они вызываются из модуля. Модули все с кодом питона. Свой код я обнародовал, простите беседовать с вами без вашего кода у меня нет времени.

Comment: Ну то есть показать пример использования вашего решения «в любом месте шаблона» вы всё-таки не можете, ясно. Придётся ставить минус за неверный ответ.